# Script to open another python file

Tags: python, windows, function, command

I have a very big project going on with python. And i need to get script what opens another .py file. I have tried to use script like this:

> os.system("example.py arg")

And it if the script in file is small like function print or something. But if they are long or something they don't work ! So i need a script that really works and opens the .py file in command promt. Thank you very much !

Comment: Is should always work. Probably the problem is in your example.py file, but I can't help you without more information about the issue.

Comment: Why not use `import`? If you're trying to use a function from another file, `import` will work.

Comment: @iurisilvio I couldn't put more information about the issue because i had formatting problems when adding script in comment. And the problem in example.py was that i didn't have shebang. Thanks to Rashan Gandi , i now have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a script using

```
os.system("example.py arg")
```

requires

- the script must be executable (+x bit)
- the must contain the shebang "#!/usr/bin/python" at the beginning of the script

See also [Should I put #! (shebang) in Python scripts, and what form should it take?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908143/should-i-put-shebang-in-python-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a function from another file, you can use [`import`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm).

```
from example import my_funct # not that 'example' does NOT have '.py' following it
my_funct() # you can now use the function from the file.
```

Alternatively, you can just import the whole script:

```
import example
example.my_funct() # you have to specify that 'my_funct' is from 'example'
```

Or, you can do:

```
from example import * # this imports all functions from 'example'
my_funct() # now you can use the function as you normally would
```

NOTE: To import a function from a module, you need to have it set up correctly. [This is how you add a function to your `PYTHONPATH`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675270/import-error-python-3-2/13675435#13675435)